# How to correct a MySQL "BEFORE INSERT" trigger's syntax?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm creating a trigger from the table ItemBorrower that is meant to update a field in the table Item. When ItemBorrower gets a new entry inserted, the currentDate field in the Item table should be updated to today's date. Here is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER checkoutItem BEFORE INSERT ON ItemBorrower

FOR EACH ROW UPDATE Item
BEGIN
    SET Item.checkoutDate = CURDATE()
    WHERE NEW.itemID = Item.itemID

END;
```

And there error I'm getting is about the last line:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'END' at line 8

I've played around with the delimeter (removing it, adding a ";" after Item.itemID), but to no apparent avail. Could be that I just did that totally wrong, too.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks,

Jona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what are you trying to accomplish from the trigger. I assumed that you have a table called item and you want to update the `checkoutDate` column with current date where the `item.itemID = the last insert id` in `ItemBorrower`.

Try this code

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER checkoutItem BEFORE INSERT ON ItemBorrower
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Item
    SET checkoutDate = CURDATE()
    WHERE itemID = NEW.itemID;

END; //
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Like. A. Charm. To make sure I understand what happened, the NEW should go along with the actual new itemID that is being made, and since the SET and WHERE correspond with the UPDATE Item, "WHERE itemID" already knows that "itemID" references the Item table. Am I right? Thanks so much!

Comment: The NEW.itemID reference the row that was added ItemBorrower.itemID. The itemID on the left reference item.itemID.